# google searchnearby api does not giving result for sightseeing.why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i when i am searching searchNearBy places which is in google searchNearBy API (link for all places which is given by google ,link:https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

my code is working fine.
but when i am searching sightseeing or 'bed and drinks' ,i am not getting any result.
but when i search these things in maps.google.com, google gives me result.

can anybody help me?
here is my code:--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Place Search</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>

<style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-top: 0.6em;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 500,
      types: ['store']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="text">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you loadng the API properly? remove the space from your script tag.

Comment: How are you searching for "bed and drinks" or "sightseeing" with the code you posted? That code is searching for Places of type "store" within 500 meters of (-33.8665433, 151.1956316). The list of types you link to doesn't include "bed and drinks" or "sightseeing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [TextSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) to get those results.

[bed and drinks](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=bed%20and%20drinks)

[sightseeing](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=sightseeing)